# How can I await an async method within a Func<string>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, func, .net-4.8

Is it possible to `await` an `async` method within a `Func<string>`?

Here's my code. You can see in the comment what I'd like to be able to do:

```
    private static string GetBearerToken()
    {
        return CacheManager.Get<string>(
            "DirectConnectApi_BearerToken",
            () =>
            {
                var response = _directConnectTokenApi
                    .Post<DirectConnectTokenResponse>()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false)
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();

                //I want to do this instead:
                //var response = await _directConnectTokenApi.Post<DirectConnectTokenResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);

                return response.result.Token;
            });

    }
```

Comment: No, it's not, because `string` is not one of the return types allowed for an `async` method. `CacheManager.Get` would have to take a `Func<Task<string>>` for this to work.

Comment: you'd have to change the return Type of both, the `Func` and `GetBearerToken` from `string` to `Task<string>` then you can make the arrow function `async () =>`

Comment: If you want to `await` in a lambda you need to put the `async` keyword before the lamda's parameter declaration. In your case it's `async () => {`

Comment: @lidqy That's not enough, the method must also return something that's awaitable (or `void`, but `async void` is weird).

Comment: @lidqy - The compiler does a sneaky conversion from `Func<Task>` to `Action` when you change `() => ` to `async () =>`. It effectively creates a "first-and-forget" method call. It changes the semantics of the lambda being called. You need to know if fire-and-forget is acceptable or not to use this.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel 
Yes if you want to await something, it must be awaitable. Seems pretty obvious.
But @DavidKlempfner said, he wanted to invoke that call:
`_directConnectTokenApi.Post<DirectConnectTokenResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);`
So don't you think it is awaitable?

Comment: @lidqy - Please be careful with your language. We don't denigrate others or blaspheme.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Please consider correcting your understanding of the term "blasphemy". "Jesus" "OMG" or "Gosh" are not blasphemic, just Everyday speech. Thank you.

And actually I am free to contradict where the "correction" is inapplicable, like it was in the case of the previous speaker's comment

Comment: @lidqy - Everyday speech depends on whom you are speaking to. If I were talking to a priest, rabbi, or vicar, my speech might vary considerably if I were hanging out in a biker's bar. This site is more like a church of programming, not a hacker's den. You should consider correcting your understanding of how the meaning of words vary in the context in which they are spoken and to the audience that hears them. It is not up to the utterer of the words to impose their will on those around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to await an async method within a Func?

No, to use async the method needs to [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-return-types#generalized-async-return-types-and-valuetasktresult)

1. void
2. `Task`
3. `Task<T>`
4. Something that looks like a task (like `ValueTask`)

None of these values is a string, so neither option is compatible with a method just returning a string.

So you will need to change the `CacheManager` to accept a `Func<Task<string>>`, as well as return a `Task<string>`. And change `GetBearerToken` to return `Task<string>`, and any method calling that, and so on. This is inherent to async/await, it tend to "spread", affecting most of the code base. If this is a problem or a feature is somewhat controversial.

If you do that you should just be able to write

```
async () => (await _directConnectTokenApi.Post<DirectConnectTokenResponse>()).Token
```